# Font Icon is now missing

Tags: css, fonts, icons

I have a font icon in use in a site I support, and an issue has been raised that it is no longer displaying, and instead displays the square not found icon.

```
font-family: 'iconfont';
display: block;
content: "\ea10";
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
```

Can anyone explain how this will have happened, as I can see this working in a  time machine and the font hasn't changed since then.

Thanks

Comment: You should know by now that question help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Since you don't provide a link or any information as to the font, OS etc...there's just **guessing** left and that's not what SO is for,

Answer (score 0):

Open devtools in browser and verify that the font exist.
Check the network tab to see if the font is downloaded when the page is loaded.

As you can see here the following fonts are downloaded.
[image]

- In your case check the style to see if the style does have this font in its list.
- Verify that no other style overwriting this font

Comment: Wait i navigated to different site for screenshot. continue to write my answer

Comment: You should only post **complete** answers...and you're guessing, not answering. Still a comment.

Comment: I needed to navigate off the page and did not want to lose the first part. The alert box asked me if i want to navigate away so i saved it first

Comment: Thanks. Font exists, its more that the content value no longer maps to an icon